# Adding CIM to AIM direct post page

Tags: transactions, authorize.net, coldfusion-11

I have a cart I built years ago using Anuthorize.net AIM direct post. The site runs on the ReturnedValues and works great.

The client wants to start saving credit card data for future transactions.

I would like to continue using the same post page and just add the CIM script as follows:
 - Run transaction in AIM
 - If tranaction is successful run CIM script to save credit card and return the key for the card.
 - To use the saved card use CIM to run transaction with saved credit card data.
 - If transaction fails call the credit card entry page so client can update information and run AIM and then CIM in the update client mode.

Here is my AIM direct post page and an example of how i work with ReturnedValues.

```
 <cflock timeout="30" throwontimeout="No" name="12345">
 <cfhttp url="https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="post">
  <cfoutput>    
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_login" value="mylogin">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_tran_key" value="mytranskey">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_version" value="3.1">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_test_request" value="FALSE">

    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_delim_data" value="TRUE">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_delim_char" value="|">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_relay_response" value="FALSE">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_invoice_num" value="#short_name#-  #order_number#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="auth_code" value="#orderID#">


    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_type" value="Auth_Capture">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_method" value="CC">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_card_num" value="#ccNumber#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_exp_date" value="#ccMonth#/#ccYearr#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_card_code" value="#ccCode#">

    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_amount" value="#NumberFormat(ORDER_TOTAL2, "9999.99")#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_description" value="Internet and Network Service Order">

    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_first_name" value="#ccName#">
    <cfhttpparam type="Formfield" name="x_last_name" value="#ccLastName#">
 </cfoutput>
 </cfhttp>
 </cflock>

 <cfoutput>
   <cfset ReturnedValues = #CFHTTP.FileContent#>
  <cfset rcode = #ListGetAt(ReturnedValues, 1, "|")#>
  <cfset reason_code = #ListGetAt(ReturnedValues, 2, "|")#>
  <cfset reason_text = #ListGetAt(ReturnedValues, 4, "|")#>
   <cfset auth_code = "#ListGetAt(ReturnedValues, 5, "|")#"> 
 </cfoutput>
```

Comment: The AIM endpoint does not support CIM functions.  Instead, you will need to use the full Authorize.Net API using XML or JSON.  http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference

Comment: Thank you rhldr. If that is so do you know where I can find a code sample in Coldfusion including the CFHTTPS tags, page headings, etc. and how to get returned values. The A/N manual confuses me and I do not know XML.